# Google Firebase Notifications for Android - when app is not running

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement a functionality wherein users get notification messages even when the app is not running (neither in foreground nor in background). Companies like Amazon do send notifications and they show up in the notification tray - when tapped, the app opens or whatever intent the message carried with it.

I have been able to implement notification handling when the app is in foreground and background... but when the app is not running, there are no notification messages received at all!

From what I searched around, I think there needs to be a Service running in the background that keeps listening to notification messages - because a service is destroyed when the app is closed. Am I going in the right direction?
Can someone point me to some code that implements or highlights the same.

Comment: If you just [add Firebase Notifications to your Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience), it will automatically show notifications in the system tray when your app is not running. You don't need to write any code for this. If that doesn't work for you, can you share the code/build files that you creates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED... actually.. the problem was MIUI.. Its security app by default disabled autostart for apps.. which blocks notifications from being shown in the system tray when the app is not running.

References:-

http://en.miui.com/thread-37783-1-1.html

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/89#issuecomment-233558184

Answer (score 0):

I you have to see the implementation of FCM for android from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

I shows complete understanding of instant notification.